# Saving only one line in JSON file with Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have JSON file with an auth key in it which I need to copy for later usage.

So I only need the one "line" from it.

What is the right way to get only one line from JSON file? File looks like this:

```
{'loginSuccess': True, 
'loginFaultMessage': None, 
'serverVersion': 'xx.xx.xx', 
'auth': '**authkey1234**'}
```

First I saved the file, then I tried to load it and pprint it, but it only changes the position of the needed auth key to output.

```
with open('auth.json') as data_file:    
    data1 = json.load(data_file)
pprint(data1) 

data1["authToken"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to create a new json file containing only the `auth` key?

Comment: Yes that, also.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'loginSuccess': True, 
'loginFaultMessage': None, 
'serverVersion': 'xx.xx.xx', 
'auth': '**authkey1234**'}
```

Aforementioned is your json.
You can access the values in your json with their respective keys.

i.e

```
print(data['auth'])
>>>'**authkey1234**'
```

Else if you want the whole key,value pair,you can iterate the json

```
for key, value in data.items():
    if key=='auth':
        print(key,':', value)
>>>auth : **authkey1234**
```